# EJB and ServletContextListener initialization

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, servletcontextlistener

I have a war with a class extending ServletContextListener and have override the contextInitialized method.

I also have a Stateless EJB that is using data from my ContextListener on initialization.
The problem is that I think sometimes the container chooses to initialize my EJB first then the ContextListener, and that of course results in some NullPointers exceptions. Is there some way to tell the container to initialize my ContextListener first and then my EJBs?

Comment: which container you are using.

Comment: @RameshPVK Weblogic 12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the EJB and the web application separate applications ? If yes you can control the deployment order as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/deployment/ChangeTheServerDeploymentOrder.html)

If they are part of the same enterprise application [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/managing.html#1014261) weblogic documentation suggests that it should be as simple as changing the order of the ejbs and your web application in application.xml

Comment: Is there any way to specify that order inside a WAR instead of af EAR?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking because a WAR contains only one web application. So how can you specify the order there? You need to choose a war and an ejb module and give one a higher 'deployment order' to ensure that it is deployed before the other.